# How to use augumented data when using transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, data-augmentation

I have used VGG16 for transfer learning and got very low accuracy. Is it possible to use data augmentation technique to increase the accuracy when using transfer learning?

```
Following is the code for better understanding:


# Show the image paths
train_path = 'myNetDB/train'      # Relative Path
valid_path = 'myNetDB/valid'
test_path = 'myNetDB/test'

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(224, 224), classes=['dog', 'cat'], batch_size=10)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(valid_path, target_size=(224, 224), classes=['dog', 'cat'], batch_size=4)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(224, 224), classes=['dog', 'cat'], batch_size=10)


vgg16_model= load_model('Fetched_VGG.h5') 

# transform the model to Sequential
model= Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]: 
    model.add(layer)

# Freezing the layers (Oppose weights to be updated)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# adding the last layer
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=4,
                    validation_data=valid_batches, validation_steps=4, epochs=5, verbose=2)


predictions = model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=1, verbose=0)
```

Comment: It is possible. But you should provide more information about how are you training your model and what is your data. Are you sure that data augmentation will solve your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to classify salt-like tiny calcium deposit in x-ray image. It's a binary classification problem. I have used, Training : 228, Validation: 58, Testing : 21. At first, I downloaded Vgg16 model from keras library, and then remove the last output layer, and freeze the model (Oppose weights to be updated). Afterwords, I added the last output layer. Then I train and test the model. My question is how to perform the data augmentation in the whole process? I know how to do data augmentation in keras, but don't know how to use transfer learning and data augmentation at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got very low accuracy, it might be that your dataset is very different from the dataset VGG16 was trained on. There are two possibilities:

1. your dataset is big enough such that you can train your model starting from the pre-trained weights.
2. your dataset is small. In this case there are no shortcuts. You should consider a simpler model than VGG16 so that you're less likely to incur in overfitting.

In both cases, to answer your question, yes, augmentation techniques, when done consciously, help increasing the accuracy.

Comment: But my question is how to use data augmentation when using transfer learning? I know how to do data augmentation in keras, but I don't know how to do data augmentation and transfer learning at the same time.

Comment: First augment your dataset. Then, initialize the weights of your network using the pre-trained weights (this is the transfer learning part). Finally, train the network.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please confirm if the following steps are correct:
(1) augment the data
(2) load the vgg16 (for example), with its weights, remove it's last output layer, and freeze the model so that the weights can not be updated.(This is the transfer learning part, right?)
(3) add an output layer, and train the model

Comment: yes, part 2 is indeed the transfer learning part. Note that if your dataset is very different from the one used to train the vgg16 and it is enough big, then you should consider to unfreeze some layers such as the last 2 or 3. And, yes, your steps are correct. If I somehow helped you, could you please accept my answer? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks!! Another question is, how the weights can be updated when using the augmented data, because for transfer learning I freez the network with its previous weights (except the last dense layer/output layer)? Is model got updated from the freeze pre-trained weights?

Comment: You need to train your model after transfering the weights.

Comment: To do that, is it the correct steps: (1) freeze the layers (2) add the output dense layer (3) train the model.  Am I right?  By this way, I can train your model starting from the pre-trained weights. Am I right?

Comment: Hi @Neb I have encounter a problem regarding transfer learning posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915233/how-to-add-customm-layers-inside-vgg16-when-doing-transfer-learning 
Just wondering if you can help anyway.