# How to add customm layers inside vgg16 when doing transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to use transfer learning using vgg16. My main concept is to train the first few layers of vgg16, and add my own layer, afterwords add the rest of the layers from vgg16, and add my own output layer to the end. To do this I follow this sequence: (1) load layers and freez layers, (2) add my layers, (3) load the rest of layers (except the output layer) [THIS IS WHERE I ENCOUNTER THE FOLLOWING ERROR] and freez the layer, (4) add output layer. Is my approach ok? If not, then where I am doing wrong? Here's the error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer block3_conv1: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 128 but got shape (None, 64, 56, 64)

The full code is here for better understanding:

```
    vgg16_model= load_model('Fetched_VGG.h5')
    vgg16_model.summary()

    model= Sequential()

    #add vgg layer (inputLayer, block1, block2)
    for layer in vgg16_model.layers[0:6]:
        model.add(layer)

    #frees
    # Freezing the layers (Oppose weights to be updated)
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    #add custom
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block66_conv1_m') )
    model.add( Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block66_conv2_m') )
    model.add( Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block66_conv3_m') )
    model.add( MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block66_pool_m'))

    # add vgg layer (block 3 to last layer (except the output dense layer))
    for layer in vgg16_model.layers[7:-1]:
        model.add(layer)

    # Freezing the layers (Oppose weights to be updated)
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # add out out layer
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions'))
    model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

As VGG16 layer 7 is expecting 128 filters you'll need to match this with your final Conv2D

```
model.add( Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block66_conv3_m') )
```

If the dimensions match you should be able to build your model but it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Your approach of adding to the middle of the VGG16 model will mean that all the downstream layers will need to be retrained

Comment: I want to add a layer inside Vgg16 model. What I am trying to to is like this: (1) use Vgg16 layer from block1 to block3 (2) add my custom layers (3) Add the rest of the vgg layers. By this way, I want to see how the model words on my data. Is it the right think to customize a model ?

Comment: Yes I understand your approach but it's not clear why you're doing this. The VGG layers you add in step 3 will have weights that depend on the original layers, they won't work with your custom layers. You'll have to train all layers you add in steps 2 and 3.

Comment: This means that it is not possible to include any layers in between the layers of VGG, right? I wanted to include some layers in between the existing vgg layers, and  only train my included layers and freeze the VGG layers to see how it works for my binary object classification tasks. From your answer, it seems like my approach was wrong, as if I freeze the layers added in step3, they won't get updated based on the weights generated  from layer 2. So, there's no point doing it, rather than training the layers added in step 2 and step 3 Am I right?

Comment: I would say it's unlikely to work and if you have enough data it'd be better to train all layers in steps 2 and 3. If you have limited training data and want to take advantage of the pretrained model you're better off customising the final layers.

Comment: You mean customising the final two fully-connected layers?